# ColdFusion dataTable returning f is undefined

Tags: datatable, coldfusion

I'm adding dataTable to my coldFusion project, but it is returning: Uncaught TypeError: f is undefined

Code:

```
<table id="webPosttable" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>DATE</th>
            <th>CK</th>
            <th>NAME</th>
            <th>IN</th>
            <th>RATE</th>
            <th>COST</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <cfoutput query="myQuery">
        <cfset totalreportin = totalreportin + val(counter)>
        <cfset totalreportcost = rate*counter + totalreportcost>
        <tr>
            <TD>#inserteddate#</TD>
            <TD>#ck#</TD>
            <TD>#fullname#</td>
            <TD><a href="link.cfm?d=#inserteddate#&ck=#ck#"  target="_blank">#counter#</a></TD>
            <td>#decimalformat(rate)#</td>
            <td>#dollarformat(rate*counter)#</td>
        </tr>
    </cfoutput>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <cfoutput>
        <tr>
            <TD colspan="3">TOTAL:</TD><td>#totalreportin#</td><TD></td><td>#dollarformat(totalreportcost)#</td>
            <TD colspan="3">AVERAGE:</TD><td><Cfif incomingreport.recordcount GT 0>#decimalformat(val(totalreportin/incomingreport.recordcount))#<Cfelse>0</CFIF></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td><td><Cfif totalreportin GT 0>#dollarformat(totalreportcost/totalreportin)#<cfelse>0</cfif></td>
        </tr>
        </cfoutput>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script>
        $('#webPosttable').DataTable({
            "lengthChange": false,
            "paging": false,
            "bInfo" : false,
            "dom": '<"pull-left"f><"pull-right"l>tip'
        });
</script>
```

Does anyone know what if something is missing in my table structure or javascript datable settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The problem won't be in your Coldfusion code, it will be the structure of your `<tfoot>` content. The number of columns in the `tfoot` doesn't match the number of columns in the rest of your table. Even the two `tr`s within your `tfoot` don't match each other.

Comment out the `tfoot` temporarily to test whether it works without, then balance up the columns and put it back in.

eg:

```
<tfoot>
    <cfoutput>
    <tr>
        <TD>TOTAL:</TD>
        <td>#totalreportin#</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>#dollarformat(totalreportcost)#</td>
        <TD>AVERAGE:</TD>
        <td><Cfif incomingreport.recordcount GT 0>#decimalformat(val(totalreportin/incomingreport.recordcount))#<Cfelse>0</CFIF></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5"></td>
        <td><Cfif totalreportin GT 0>#dollarformat(totalreportcost/totalreportin)#<cfelse>0</cfif></td>
    </tr>
    </cfoutput>
</tfoot>
```

If you still have errors after that then I'd advise updating the question to include the code showing which version of jQuery+datatables you're including and where and how you're including it. You may also need to wrap your script in a `$(document).ready( function () { ...`